# jquery Countdown timer NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdowntimer

Hi I'm new with JS and jQuery, and I have a problem with a simple countdown timer.

When I type some value into input it translates into NaN (instead of number) in my countdown timer.

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    var $input = $('#time'),
        seconds = parseInt($input.val()),
        $start = $('button');

    $start.on('click', function() {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {

            switch (seconds) {
                case 0:
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    console.log("Time's UP!");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    console.log("Do końca pozostała " + seconds + " sekunda"); /*polish gramaticall variation*/
                    break;
                case 4:
                case 3:
                case 2:
                    console.log("Do końca pozostało " + seconds + " sekundy"); /*polish gramaticall variation*/
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("Do końca pozostało " + seconds + " sekund"); /*polish gramaticall variation*/
            }
            seconds = seconds - 1;
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<label for="time">Set time in seconds </label>
<input type="text" id="time">
<button>Start</button>
```

Comment: `seconds = parseInt($input.val())` the value of seconds will be the value that set on page load , it's never updating at any instance. So it will be always NaN.

Comment: so replace `seconds` with `$input.val()` inside the click event function, this may solve your problem

Comment: NaN means Not a Number incase you didn't know. Could help detect the cause in future struggles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning the value of `seconds` only on `document.ready` so it only ever has its initial value of `""` - which parses to `NaN`. Move it inside your `.click` handler so that seconds is updated on each button click:

```
var seconds = 0;
$start.on('click', function(){
    seconds = parseInt($input.val(), 10); // Always pass a radix to parseInt
    ....
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dm6ou8o/)

Comment: This is a very important clue, thx for help now everything is fine :-)